# Find a CDF of a random variable that depends on another random variable

Tags: integration, random-variables

I know there are lots of topics, I searched, nothing could help me.
We have:
$$f_X\left(t\right)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{2}&1\le \left|t\right|\le 2\\ 0&else\end{cases},\:\:\:Y=\begin{cases}e^X&\frac{3}{2}\le \left|X\right|\le 2\\ 1&1\le \left|X\right|<\frac{3}{2}\end{cases}$$
as $X$ is continuous random variable. find $P(Y\le t)$.
I have the solution of the professor, but could not understand the domain and ranges and such.. I did the graph also[image]
But still could not see what he did:

I will be very happy if someone can tell me how to understand the solution.
I don't know how he reached $t>e^2$ or $t<e^{-2}$ and such.. on what it depends on? when do I switch domains?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the ranges in your professor's solution, note that by the definition of $Y$ its range is $$[e^{-2}, e^{-3/2}]\cup \{1\}\cup [e^{3/2}, e^2].$$
I hope that it is now quite clear that what your professor did was to look at the range of $Y$ and to then choose $t$ so that we are able to express $Y$ in terms of $X$ and to compute the CDF quite easily. For instance, we obviously have $$\mathbb{P}(Y\le t)=0$$ for $t<e^{-2}$.
Now, if $e^{-2}\le t\le e^{-3/2}$, note that $Y\le t$  if and only if $Y=e^X$ (so $X=\ln Y$) and $-2\le X\le -3/2$, so $$\mathbb{P}(Y\le t)=\mathbb{P}(\ln Y\le \ln t)=\mathbb{P}(X\le \ln t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\ln t}f_X(x)\, dx=\int_{-2}^{\ln t}\frac{1}{2} \, dx=\frac{1}{2}(\ln t+2)$$ if $e^{-2}\le t \le e^{-3/2}$.
If you proceed like this, you will get precisely your professor's answer (let me know if you need some help with the remaining computations).

LE: Since the OP still has some trouble understanding this, I will also compute the CDF on the interval $(e^{-3/2}, 1]$.

If $e^{-3/2}< t\le 1$, we have $$\mathbb{P}(Y\le t)=\mathbb{P}(Y\le e^{-3/2})+\mathbb{P}(e^{-3/2}< Y\le t).$$
We have $\displaystyle \mathbb{P}(Y\le e^{-3/2})=\int_{-2}^{-3/2}\frac{1}{2} \, dx=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{3}{2}+2\right)=\frac{1}{4}$ by our previous computations and $\mathbb{P}(e^{-3/2}\le Y\le t)=0$ (can you see why?), so $$\mathbb{P}(Y\le t)=\frac{1}{4}$$ if $e^{-3/2}< t\le 1$.

Comment: Hi, huge thanks for the explanation............... Basically, the range of $Y$ is from the split function right? just so I wont understand it not correctly......... And I think I might understand now........ Now it is a little late in my time, I will wake up in the morning and try this again!! again, huge thanks.

Comment: Actually, I will be happy to understand why is there $\frac 3 2$........ since the values do not have it....... should that be $1$ in that case? like $e^X$ as you did and the answer? same as $-\frac 3 2$, why is it like that and not constant 1? since the value is really 1, no idea from where that came from

Comment: @LearningToCode I don't think I can quite follow your question. Where exactly do you think that we should have $1$ instead of $-3/2$ for instance?

Comment: Hi........ You decided the ranges of $F_y(t)$ based on the values of axis Y, no? there we have $e^2$, $e{\frac 3 2}$, $1$, $e^-{\frac 3 2}$ and $e^{-2}$............ So I just dont see why we suddenly have $\frac 3 2$ and not 1

Comment: @LearningToCode Yes, you are correct, you basically get those ranges for $t$ by looking at the values of $Y$ (for example, since we always have $Y\ge e^{-2}$, we simply conclude that for all $t<e^{-2}$ we have $F_Y(t)=0$). As for why we have $e^{3/2}$ there, note that $e^{3/2}\le Y \le e^2$ if $3/2\le X\le 2$, so this is why we don't directly jump to $1$ from $e^2$.

Comment: Hi, I did not talk about $e^{\frac 3 2}$, I talked about why we have $\frac 3 2$ instead of $1$.......... Look at the graph, you see point $\frac 3 2$? no, you see 1? yes, that is my concern here......................... I mean, at the y Axis, we dont have that number, but in the answer, you do have, so where does the $\frac 3 2$ comes from? Hope you understand what I said, my english is not at its best :\

Comment: @LearningToCode we have $3/2$ in the answer because if we look at the definition of $Y$ we may see that $Y=1$ if $1\le |X| <3/2$. This is why on the graph you have $3/2$ on the $X$-axis and $1$ on the $Y$-axis (your random variable $Y$ is a function of the random variable $X$).

Comment: Wait, so the range of the function, of $F_z(t)$, it depends on the x axis, with applying Y, I think I understand now. I thought it depended on the Y axis... that was my mistake. I will try now and update!! Thanks!!

Comment: Uhh, I am getting very frustrated at myself... I understood the first two ranges from bottom execept that $\frac 3 2$ :( I still dont see why we have that instead of 1. I cannot see what you see in here

Comment: @LearningToCode I have just added the computations for the third range from the bottom. Is it clear now? To finish the problem you just have to do the same thing for the remaining ranges.

Comment: Wow, you are king, so now I understand why the $\frac 3 2$, that is what was missing to me, this so so much simpler, now I think I understand!! huge thanks!!